# Replace value with src of an image?

Tags: jquery, replace, preview

I'm trying to take the src of an image and append it to the value of a text input:

```
$(".detail-template").on("click", ".btn-primary", function(e) {
    var image = $(".detail_template").find("img").attr("src");
    $('input[value="stock-ref"]').val(image);
});
```

But it is just resulting in a blank input field?

The webpage is here: http://fuzzionwallart.co.uk/store2/vinyl-wall-art/vinyl-wall-art-contemporary/vinyl-wall-art-buddah

Basically we're wanting to take the src of the preview and put it into the text input so that we know which image the customer has chosen. But I Can't get it to work to save my life!

Comment: Try and isolate the problem. Is the `image` variable being populated? Or is it failing when it is trying to set the value in the input?

Comment: It may be just me, but to me it looks like just a number of random lines of code. 
What did `$('input[value="stock-ref"]').val(image);` mean to do?

Answer (score 2):

you need chech youy html source, your div.detail-template does not have any IMG.
So this is reason why your code does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

First the div your are searching is classed "detail-template", not "detail_template". Then the only img tag in div.detail-template i could find has an empty "src" attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in addition to Anton's answer, your input jQuery selector looks wrong (at least if you are expecting this to work more than once).

Do you mean to select it via it's name or ID instead?

```
$('input[name="stock-ref"]').val(image);
```